# Custom data on each socket.io session on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a simple module like this:

```
module.exports = function (io, c) {

    c.on('connection', function (socket) {

      var customVariable = 0;

      socket.on('test', function (data) {
            customVariable = 5;
      });
    });
```

When i set `customVariable` to for example `5` it becomes `5` for `every connected user`.

I want to store some variables for each individual user. How can i achieve this? I use Node.js 6 with socket.io lib (latest). Is it wise to use this method OR should I make an array/collection and assign my variables to my socket id like;

```
var users = [
  socketId: {
     //my data goes here...
  }
];
```

Comment: You should consider a database, unless you want that info to disappear anytime the process shuts down.

Comment: thanks for the hint. of course I already have it. But for example i have few variables to assign to only current socket session. When socket session get lost or shutdown, variable should disappear. For example when user connected to server, i want to store userId (against database) inside of my js file so i can easily grab user id without querying database each time.

Comment: An object with the socketIds as keys sounds like a good way if you don't want to store them in a database.

Comment: @Syc, yes i probably go with it. I think keeping it inside of an array within memory is faster than reading from database. Imagine that I fetch `select user_id from sessions where socket_id = ?` **everytime** a request made to my socket.io server instead of just saying `arr[socketId].user_id`. Am I thinking still wrong? Should I even query against db each time?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762017/node-js-store-object-in-memory-or-database

Comment: You can also add property `socket.userid = userIdFromDatabase` and use it  until a socket disconnects

Comment: @mk12ok, wow didn't knew that. Thanks mate :) I am evaluating this right now.